# symfony2 routing defaults

Tags: php, symfony, symfony-routing

I have defined a controller with annotation

```
@Route("/add,{elId},{elType},{parentId}",name="MeaTask_Add", defaults={"elId"=null,"elType"=null, "parentId"=null})
public function addAction($elId=null, $elType=null, $parentId=null, Request $request){
```

I try to use it like here

```
$this->generateUrl('MeaTask_Add',array(
                    'parentId'=>$parentId         
                ))
```

and get

```
  An exception has been thrown during the rendering of a template ("Parameter "elType" for route "MeaTask_Add" must match "[^/,]++" ("" given) to generate a corresponding URL.")
```

Answer (score 0):

```
@Route("/add/{elId}/{elType}/{parentId}",name="MeaTask_Add", defaults={"elId"=null,"elType"=null, "parentId"=null})
```

try with slashes i don't the annotation route url can handle coma.